# postgresql st_contains performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

```
SELECT
  a.geom, 'tk' category,
  ROUND(avg(tk), 1) tk
FROM
  tb_grid_4326_100m a left outer join 
(
  SELECT
    tk-273.15 tk, geom
  FROM
    tb_points
  WHERE
    hour = '23'
) b ON st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY
  a.geom
```

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=54632324.85..54648025.25 rows=50698 width=184) (actual time=8522.042..8665.129 rows=50698 loops=1)                                   |
  Group Key: a.geom                                                                                                                                                 |
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=54632324.85..54646504.31 rows=101396 width=152) (actual time=8522.032..8598.567 rows=50698 loops=1)                                       |
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                          |
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                         |
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=54631324.83..54633800.68 rows=50698 width=152) (actual time=8490.577..8512.725 rows=16899 loops=3)                        |
              Group Key: a.geom                                                                                                                                     |
              ->  Sort  (cost=54631324.83..54631785.36 rows=184212 width=130) (actual time=8490.557..8495.249 rows=16996 loops=3)                                   |
                    Sort Key: a.geom                                                                                                                                |
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2296kB                                                                                                       |
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2304kB                                                                                            |
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2296kB                                                                                            |
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.41..54602621.56 rows=184212 width=130) (actual time=1.729..8475.942 rows=16996 loops=3)                      |
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tb_grid_4326_100m a  (cost=0.00..5866.24 rows=21124 width=120) (actual time=0.724..2.846 rows=16899 loops=3)     |
                          ->  Index Scan using sidx_tb_points on tb_points  (cost=0.41..2584.48 rows=10 width=42) (actual time=0.351..0.501 rows=1 loops=50698)|
                                Index Cond: (((hour)::text = '23'::text) AND (geom @ a.geom))                                                                       |
                                Filter: st_contains(a.geom, geom)                                                                                                   |
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                           |
Planning Time: 1.372 ms                                                                                                                                             |
Execution Time: 8667.418 ms                                                                                                                                         |
```

I want to join 100m grid table, 100,000 points table using st_contains function.
The 100m grid table has 75,769 records, and tb_points table has 2,434,536 records.
When a time condition is given, the tb_points table returns about 100,000 records.
(As a result, about 75,000 records JOIN about 100,000 records.)

(Index information)
100m grid table using gist(geom),

tb_points table using gist(hour, geom)

It took 30 seconds. How can i imporve the performance?

Comment: What is the type of the 'hour' column?  It seems pretty weird that the plan is casting it to numeric.

Comment: @jjanes Its type is varchar. Is this related to the performance?

Comment: Could you share the index definition? Almost all time is spend in the index scan and almost all results are thrown away... See the filter, some items are missing in the index

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've already wrote the index definition. The grid table using gist(geom), points table using gist(hour, geom).

Comment: You can't use an index on a varchar to efficiently search for a numeric.  I don't know that that fully explains the performance problem. But it surely doesn't help.

Comment: @IamMegy: Must be me, but I don't see any DDL for your index in this topic... Could you show me where the CREATE INDEX statement can be found?

Comment: I can't get the plan you show from the query you show.  I would need to add an explicit cast to the hour column to get it to generate that plan.  PostgreSQL won't implicitly cast varchar to numeric, it would instead throw an operator-does-not-exist error.

Comment: @FrankHeikens
CREATE INDEX sidx_tb_points ON public.tb_points USING gist (hour, geom);
CREATE INDEX sidx_tb_grid_4326_100m_geom ON public.tb_grid_4326_100m USING gist (geom);

Comment: @jjanes The hour column is varchar(2), so i changed the hour parameter to varchar type. But it still took 30 seconds. I edited my query and plan in my main text.

Comment: Your new plan shows it taking 8.6 seconds, not 30.

Comment: It isn't clear if your time is going to CPU or to IO.  With a multicolumn gist index, either one of those seems plausible.  If you turn track_io_timing on and then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, it should clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give a definitive answer, but here are several things you can try:

For a multicolumn gist index, it is often a good idea to put the most selectively used column first.  In your case, that would have the index be on `(geom, hour)`, not `(hour, geom)`.  On the other hand, it can also be better to put the faster column first, and testing for scalar equality should be much faster than testing for containment.  You would have to do the test and see which factor is more important for you.

You could try for an Index-only scan, which doesn't need to visit the table. That could save a lot of random IO.  Do do that you would need the index `gist (hour, geom) INCLUDE (tk, geom)`.  The geom column in a gist index is not considered to be "returnable", so it also needs to be put in the INCLUDE part into order to get the IOS.

Finally, you could partition the table tb_points on "hour".  Then you wouldn't need to put "hour" into the gist index, as it is already fulfilled by the partitioning.

And these can be mixed and matched, so you could also swap the column order in the INCLUDE index, or you could try to get both partitioning and the INCLUDE index working together.

Comment: Thank you so much. I change the index on (geom, hour) to (hour, geom), It only took about 2 seconds!!